# Kotlin RxJava2 Flowable PublishSubject doesn't emit data onNext

Tags: kotlin, rx-java2

I know on stackoverflow we have a lot of similar questions, but i really don't know what i'm doing wrong.

I have list objects.

```
val applicationList: MutableList<Application> = generateApplications()
```

After i create PublishSubject and Flowable

```
val applicationsPublishSubject = PublishSubject.create<List<Application>>()
val applicationsFlowable =  applicationsPublishSubject.toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.LATEST) 
// The second variant
// applicationsFlowable = Flowable.fromPublisher<List<Application>> { applicationsPublishSubject }
```

After i generate applications and i call

```
applicationsPublishSubject.onNext(applicationList);
```

This is my getFlowable method:

```
override fun getApplications(): Flowable<List<Application>> {
    return applicationsFlowable
}
```

And this is how i subscribe to my flowable:

```
compositeDisposable.add(dataSource.getApplications()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe({
            getViewState().setApplicationList(it)
        }, {
            Log.e("ApplicationsPresenter", it.toString())
        }))
```

But method onNext never calls.
If i use this code, it works perfect.

```
override fun getApplications(): Flowable<List<Application>> {
    return Flowable.just(applicationList)
}
```

But it's not exactly what i want. Because when i will create new Application object, i want to emit new list to my applicationsFlowable.

```
override fun createApplication(name: String): Single<Application> {
    val application = generateApplication(name)
    applicationsPublishSubject.onNext(applicationList)
    return Single.just(application)
}
```

What i'm doing wrong ??

Comment: You may be sending the event sooner than there is a subscriber to the flow. Please check `applicationsPublishSubject.hasObservers()` before calling `onNext` to see if this is the case or not.

Answer (score 0):

It was my mistake. Just use BehaviorSubject instead PublishSubject.